# Do I need an apartment when I have an office?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If I have a CEO office in *GTA Online*, do I need an apartment? As the office has living quarters and a garage.

Comment: I don't think you really "need" an apartment at all in GTA-Online.  It's just to store cars in and to be able to initiate heists (in the higher end ones) - all of which is optional.

Comment: I was more meaning, could I sell the apartment and “live” in my office? Or does the game require me to have one of each type of property?

Comment: The game doesn't require you to have any properties; you only need certain properties to do certain types of missions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't **need** any properties in GTA Online, but purchasing them will offer benefits.

The CEO offices do offer all the comforts of an apartment including bed, shower, and changing facilties but they lack a planning room.

[A planning room](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204193307-Heist-Room-in-House), which is part of the high-end apartments, will be required if you want to be able to start hiests yourself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/230029)

Comment: @TimmyJim Really? It seems like a proper answer to me, but I don't know anything about the game.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer what the poster said is correct but the question is asking (basically) if you have a CEO office if you can use it the same way as an apartment. This answer in my opinion would be better as a comment since it is a one liner stating something that I've already said as a comment, and doesn't address any other differences between a CEO office and an apartment in the game.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, it's saying it's impossible to start heists from CEO offices, and that a "high end" apartment is required. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer correct.

Comment: The OP's comments do seem to show some confusion on their part, but I don't think this answer is not trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a house to live in at all. New players start off with no houses as well, so I supposed you can live without a house. **BUT** I dont think you can sell a house tho.